# Windows Authentication Doesn't Work Locally

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-7

I have a box running SQL Server 7 (I know) on Windows XP (I know).

All of the sudden, I'm unable to use Windows authentication to connect to the database from the local machine.

I can connect using SQL authentication on the local machine.

I can connect using both SQL and Windows authentication from another machine.

Here's the error I get when using Query Analyzer to connect to the local database using Windows authentication.

[image: Error Message]

I've tried connecting using both the machine name, . and localhost.

[image: Client Network Settings]

Any ideas?

Thanks!

**Update:  Added Screenshot of server protocols**

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the SQL Server Service is running?

Comment: Yes, it is definitely running.  I can connect using SQL authentication, just not Windows authentication.  Windows authentication works if I'm connecting FROM another machine.

Comment: Has your password expired or something like that?

Comment: My password hasn't expired.  We've tried multiple Windows accounts and they all get the error.  I even created a new local user on the box, gave it db access and it gets the error.  The domain accounts with access all work as long as we're connecting to the db on HP00333198 from another machine.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the protocols which are enabled for the server?  The screenshot you have is the client network protocols.

Comment: See if you can add "shared memory" to the server protocols. (I honestly don't remember is SQL 7 supports shared memory protocol or not, it's been years since I've looked at SQL 7.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never figured out the root cause of the problem, but installing SQL Server 7 SP4 fixed the issue.